# "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" in savefig when using usetex:true

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using savefig with text.usetex:true in matplotlib, I get `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

EDIT: The solution for me was to upgrade matplotlib from 2.1.0 to 3.0.2

I can save to a png format with usetex:true but not pdf. I can save to pdf with usetex:false. Here is the minimal code required to produce the error:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('pdf')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
fig.savefig('test.pdf')
```

I have Miktex 2.9 installed, and also the most recent versions of dvipng and Ghostscript as mentionned here: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/usetex.html?highlight=usetex

I added the following to my path:

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
```

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.6.3 and matplotlib 2.1.0.

I also tried deleting my .matplotlib/tex.cache directory, with no success.

Full traceback:

```
File ".\usetex.py", line 9, in <module>
    fig.savefig('test.pdf')
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1814, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2259, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py", line 2592, in print_pdf
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1295, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2399, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1138, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 282, in draw
    self.label1.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 799, in draw
    mtext=mtext)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py", line 1944, in draw_tex
    pdfname = self.file.dviFontName(dvifont)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py", line 688, in dviFontName
    psfont = self.texFontMap[dvifont.texname]
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 866, in __getitem__
    fn = find_tex_file(fn)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 1045, in find_tex_file
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 461, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Did you try to use `savefig(b'test.pdf')`?

Comment: I tested the code with matplotlib 2.0.2, 2.2.2, 3.0.1 with python 3.6 on windows and miktex 2.9 and it works fine. I do not currently have any 2.1.0 environment for testing though, but maybe it's still a problem that can be resolved by updating matplotlib.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I upgraded to 3.0.2 and it works, thank you.

Comment: @Bakuriu I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Probably rather answer your own question, instead of writing the answer in the question, after all, a question is still a question, right? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I upgraded matplotlib from 2.1.0 to 3.0.2 and the error doesn't show up anymore.